# GoLang: Preload not working properly, incorrectly adding WHERE (1 <> 1) to my queries?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have my user struct

```
type User struct {
    ID                   uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;"`
    ...
    Roles                []*Role `gorm:"many2many:user_roles_map"`
}

func (User) TableName() string {
    return "user"
}
```

and my Role struct

```
type Role struct {
    ID       int64 `gorm:"type:bigserial;primaryKey"`
    RoleName string
    Users    []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_roles_map"`
}

func (Role) TableName() string {
    return "role"
}
```

However, when I use db.Preload("Roles"), the query generated returns no results, because this is the query:

`SELECT * FROM "role" INNER JOIN "user_roles_map" ON "user_roles_map"."role_id" = "role"."id" WHERE (1 <> 1)`

I've tried manually adding conditions to the Preload like this:

```
db.Debug().Preload("Roles", func(d *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {     
    return d.Where("user_id = ?", id)    
}).First(&user, "id = ?", id)
```

Which generates the roles query with the correct condition, but still adds the 1 <> 1 condition nullifying my query. Generated query from this code:

`SELECT * FROM "role" INNER JOIN "user_roles_map" ON "user_roles_map"."role_id" = "role"."id" WHERE (user_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') AND (1 <> 1)`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here and why this 1 <> 1 condition keeps getting added to my preload query? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't technically resolved the issue but I figured out the cause, apparently the uuid of all 0's is considered a null value, and is treated as a special case by gorm, resulting in the botched query. I guess I'll have to change the UUID of my default reserved user